# Karnaugh Map minimal SOP form

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have a hoemwork and must be done without boolean algebra

> Please simplify this function with K-Map only
>
> $F = ABC + A' . B . (A' . D')'$

I know this can be easily solve by using boolean algebra
and I have tried it

> $F = A.B.C + A' . B . (A' . D')'$
>   $F = A.B.C + A' . B . (A + C)$
>   $F = A.B.C + A' . A . B + A' . B . C$
>   $F = A.B.C + 0 . B + A' . B . C$
>   $F = A.B.C + A' . B . C$
>   $F = B.C.(A + A')$
>   $F = B.C$
>   So, the answer is **BC**

But when i'm trying to solve with K-Map only then there is a problem
$F = A . B . C + A' . B . (A' . C')'$

The $A.B.C$ is $1 1 1$ right?
but what about $A' . B . (A' . C')'$?

Comment: One possibility would be to construct a truth table and see which rows evaluate to $1$.

Comment: @benguin, would you like to elaborate what do you mean? Do I need to make $A'.B.(A'.C')'$ truth table?

Comment: You can make one for the entire function.

Comment: @benguin, Would you like to explain what do you mean by make one for the entire function? I still don't understand